# Subtracting two SimpleDateFormat to get the difference in days

Tags: java, android, time, simpledateformat

I'm making a simple app where i get I get time is as a long and the current time from calendar.getInstance() (the current time).

I would like to check the difference in days between the 2 dates.

```
Long date1 = 1499175346756l;

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy.HH.mm.ss");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(c.getTime());
```

Comment: so whats the problem in subtracting two longs and converting the difference to some other visible format?

Comment: @pskink Yes that would work.

Comment: also you can check `android.text.format.DateUtils` for some helper methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i am not wrong, you have both the dates in "Long type", than you can try the following code

```
         Calendar firstDate = Calendar.getInstance();
         Calendar lastDate = Calendar.getInstance();
         Date startDate = firstDate.getTime();
         Date endDate = lastDate.getTime();

         long startTime = startDate.getTime();
         long endTime = endDate.getTime();
         long diffTime = endTime - startTime;
         long diffDays = diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
```